# Three.js Click and Drag - Object Lagging Behind Pointer

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js, webgl

I've created a near exact implementation of the Three.js Draggable Cubes example, except that my implementation ignores the z axis for movement in 2D. The example can be found here: http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_interactive_draggablecubes

While I am able to click and move around my object, if I move the mouse too fast, the object will lag behind; the mouse pointer will move to it's location and then the object will follow the mouses path to the location. This issue is also noticeable in the Three.js example. Try dragging one of the cubes at anything beyond a moderate speed.

I've tried a few things to get the object to be directly under the mouse pointer but none have worked. The closest I think I might have come to a solution was by changing the mouse position update in the MouseMove event. However, it appears that the Three.js implementation of the code returns values between 1 and -1 rather than the screen X and Y coordinates, which leads me to wonder if the original implementation is causing the lag.

```
//Original Implementation - Works With Lag
mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
console.log(mouse.x + "," + mouse.y); //Output: -0.9729166666666667,0.8596858638743455

//My Implementation - Does Not Work
mouse.x = event.clientX - (window.innerWidth / 2);
mouse.y = event.clientY - (window.innerHeight / 2);
console.log(mouse.x + "," + mouse.y); //Output: -934,-410.5

//Update Function
void Update()
{
    var vector = new THREE.Vector3(mouse.x, mouse.y, 1);
    projector.unprojectVector(vector, camera);

    var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(camera.position, vector.sub(camera.position).normalize());

    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObject(plane);
    meshToMove.position.x = intersects[0].point.x;
    meshToMove.position.y = intersects[0].point.y;
}

//Main Loop
function Loop()
{
    Update();
    Render();

    requestAnimationFrame(Loop);
}
```

---

### **Q: How can I update the three.js Draggable Cubes example so that objects don't lag behind the mouse during a click and drag?**

Comment: Handling inputs is always very slow, if you want to be able to move fast, you'll have to interpolate... A thing i would try, though, is to avoid accessing the DOM in the handler : cache innerWidth/Height. Or rather, cache their invert, so you can later multiply instead of dividing.

Comment: you ever figure this one out?

Comment: It's more than likely an issue with the way you are drawing geometries.  Try using a BufferGeometry.  I have been able to draw 200,000 boxes with no pan lag.